# Using '=' for Classes without Defining '=' Operator in C++

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

Is the following assignment valid?

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    A(int k): a(k){}
}
void main() {
    A first (5);
    A second;
    second = first;
}
```

If it is valid, what happens for second? Does C++ makes a deep copy? Or a shallow copy?

Comment: default memberwise assignment. Memberwise assignment consists of copying one object to the other, a member at a time, as if assigning each member individually.

Comment: If you don't provide a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, compiler will generate one, but this doesn't mean you can skip it _always_

Comment: It's only fine as long as the class does not contain a pointer. Otherwise you'd get shallow copies.

Comment: there is compilation error in your code in line `A second;` !! isn't ? you have no default constructor (with no parameter) as you define your constructor !

Comment: @Brandon: This depends entirely on what these pointers represent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are new to C++, perhaps a student?

You are lucky, since the data member for your A class is an integer. Which is a plain old data type. Called POD for short. BTW: You tagged your question  with copy-constructor, but demonstrated in your example an assignment operator.

They are two different things.

A copy constructor makes a new instance based off of another instance. Like this:

```
class A
{
public:
   A(A& other) { ... }
};
```

An assignment operator looks like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    const A& operator=(const A& other) { ... }
};
```

Since you did not provide your own assignment operator, the compiler made one for you. In fact the compiler will also make a destructor for you too. Isn't that nice? Well don't always trust your compiler. If your classes have anything beyond Plain old Data, then please get in the habit of providing your own constructors, destructors, assignment operators. It's a rule I live by. I'd hate to have a bug that takes 2 days to track down to say... a memory leak due to my forgetting to deallocate memory in a destructor.

In your case, the compiler made a shallow copy for you. A compiler will never make a deep copy for you. You have to do that yourself.

Comment: btw, my favorite article on assignment operators. Old but good: http://www.icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_anatomy_of_the_assignment_operator.html

Comment: Can also enable (for gcc/g++) `-Weffc++` as well. Which will warn when a class has a pointer data member with no copy constructor or assignment operator. If you do this with `-werror` to treat warnings as errors, you catch all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote one form of constructor, compiler will not provide default constructor so your declaration 'A second;' will not compile. You could possibly do A second(0); and then second = first;